# AutoMapper - IncludeBase, resolvers overrides mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I ran into a problem with mapping inheritance. I can't remap with MapFrom a property that is mapped in the base mapping through a resolver. I want to get a pulse in Value property, when i map <ReadingModel, HealthDataHistoryPulseCreateModel>. If I use a resolver in the base map, I'll still get Spo2 in Value, not Pulse. But if I use a simple MapFrom in the base map, I'll get Pulse:

```
cfg.CreateMap<ReadingModel, HistoryCreateModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, _ => _.MapFrom<HealthMeasurementValueResolver>()) // i get spo2 in the inherited mapping
    //.ForMember(dest => dest.Value, _ => _.MapFrom(src => (float) src.Spo2)) // i get pulse in the inherited mapping
    .ForAllOtherMembers(_ => _.Ignore());
        
cfg.CreateMap<ReadingModel, HealthDataHistoryPulseCreateModel>()
    .IncludeBase<ReadingModel, HistoryCreateModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, _ => _.MapFrom(src => (float) src.Pulse));
```

How can i use the resolver in the base map and get the pulse in the inherited map?

Here's a code example: [dotnetfiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/skWeRt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade. Otherwise, you'll have to use a resolver in the derived map too. The expectation was that nobody would write that code :) So that's just an accident of the implementation. The idea is for the derived map to override the base map and that's what happens in AM 11 in this case.